# Operational amplifier - why average voltage is not stright related to pulse to duty cycle?

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode

I have a strange problem, that I cant find an answer.
I have slow photodiode (about 2MHz) and fast, pulsed laser light source (pulses 10 to 500ns). Im trying to measure optical output power. To do it Im using operational amplifier and low pass filter.
Pulses parameters: frequency 10kHz, pulse time 500ns.
Here is my LT spice circuit.
[image: circuit]

And here is a chart
[image: inputcurret_outputvoltage]

I thought that after low pass filter should be directly linear to duty cycle. So for 10kHz, and 500ns pulse duration I have amplitude for ex 0,6V, so for the same frequency but pulse duration 250ns (half of previous duration), amplitude will be 0,3V. But there in fact it is about 0,37V.
Here is example table for 100-700ns pulses, and amplitude.

[image]

Im really confused what is going on.

EDIT:
I was not clear. Simulation works great, and as brhans said there is an offset. But im really confused about real circuit, that Ihave made. And there is some non linearity.

[image]

Comment: Looks (superficially) linear to me. There's an *offset*, but it's still linear. What output do you get with a 0ns "pulse"?

Comment: I was going to say the same as brhans, your results seem linear, thus the question doesn't really make sense. You are maybe wondering why there is an offset?

Comment: *But there in fact it is about 0,37V* I only see a blue curve varying between -80 uV and +800 uV. Where is your 0.37 V coming from? Your input current is 100 uA, your OTA has a transconductance (at DC) of 1 kohm (Rf) so at most you would get 100 uA * 1 k = 100 mV at the output of the opamp. What if you make Cf **much smaller** like 100 pF instead of 1uF?

Comment: Thank you for yours answer. I was not quite clear. I can not use 1uF, becasue there is only 200 pulses, and for the 1uF capacitance time delay is too long.

Comment: Please look at EDITed post. Non linearity appears on real circuit.

Comment: Don't know if this accounts for your non-linearity, but OP27 has a slew rate of 2.8V/uSec.

Comment: How are you generating the input for the "real circuit"? Can you use a pulse generator with known good behavior? The non-linearity does not look that bad to me...how linear do you need it to be?

Comment: Look at the waveform on your virtual earth (IN-). Yes it should be 0 : but that assumes an ideal (or at least fast enough) opamp. Anything else there is an error waveform, which tells you that either more bandwidth, or higher slew rate,  or more gain at the error spectral frequencies is required because the feedback loop has lost control.  And opamps are pretty non-linear when not operating closed loop.

Comment: Thank you for all answers. I have found where the issue was. When I use pulse generator linearity error is lower than 1%, but the problem is when I'm using optical pulses to drive op amp. The problem is related to maximum peak power of laser otpical pulses, it was way too much, so I change my circuit and added capacitance at the input, and everything now is working like a charm.